# Change innerhtml of all h2 elements within div

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

This is probably a stupid mistake, but i can't seem to get this to work.
I'm trying to change the innerhtml of all the H2 elements withing the div whose id=variable id.

```
var numberOfQuestions = $('.question').length;
  var id = "question"+(numberOfQuestions);
  clone.id=id;
  document.documentElement.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName( "h2" ).innerhtml= "Question"+(numberOfQuestions);
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here: `document.documentElement.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName( "h2" ).innerhtml= "Question"+(numberOfQuestions);`
The nrtire script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function copyAppendRow() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  var clone=question.cloneNode(true);
  var numberOfQuestions = $('.question').length;
  var id = "question"+(numberOfQuestions);
  clone.id=id;
  var questiondiv = document.getElementById(id);
var h2s = questiondiv.getElementsByTagName("h2");
for(var h = 0; h < h2s.length; h++ ) {
  h2s[h].innerHTML = "Question"+(numberOfQuestions); }
  if($('#questionsuccess').css('display') == 'none'){
  $('#questionsuccess').fadeIn('fast');
 $('#questionsuccess').fadeOut(4000);
  }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you mean something like:

```
var divEle = document.getElementById("yourDivId");
var h2s = divEle.getElementsByTagName("h2");
for(var h = 0; h < h2s.length; h++ ) {
  h2s[h].innerHTML = "Question"+(numberOfQuestions);
}
```

OR 
jQuery way:

```
$("#"+yourDivId + " > h2").html("Question"+(numberOfQuestions));
```

Comment: seems about right. but doesn't seem to work. I've added my full script so you can see if anything is wrong their. Thanks.

Comment: oh wow. at some point i deleted the append part of my script. yours works perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see from your first line that you are already using jQuery, so make life easy for yourself and use it to do this task.

```
$('#' + id + ' h2').html( 'Question ' + numberOfQuestions );
```

The jQuery selectors work just like CSS selectors. So this line of code finds the element with your variable `id` as its' id and gets all the h2 tags within that element. `.html` is a jQuery method that sets the inner HTML of an element.